# How to convert a json struture from simple to complex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, time-series

I have this simple data structure to a complex structure:

```
{"item" :  "Light",
"value":  39,
"time" :  151869596954},

{"item" :  "Bat",
"value":  3.412,
"time" :  1518695969954},

{"item" :  "Humidity",
"value":  56,
"time" :  1518697292308},

{"item" : "InternalTemperature",
"value": 22.2,
"time" : 1518697292308}]
```

and I am trying to convert it into using javascript:

```
[
  {
    time: 1518697292308,
    InternalTemperature : 22,
    Humidity : 33,
    Bat : 9
  }
]
```

Comment: How do I go about that?

Comment: See my updated code

Comment: @Palvo I think we ommited the timestamp because am displaying this on a time-series graphs

Comment: Yeah. You right. I change my code in a few minutes to resolve it

Comment: If you need to avoid **Light** in result just add skip condition in callback

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can easily do it by `reduce` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const result = [{"item" :  "Light",
        "value":  39,
        "time" :  1518695969954},
    
        {"item" :  "Bat",
            "value":  3.412,
            "time" :  1518695969954},
    
        {"item" :  "Humidity",
            "value":  56,
            "time" :  1518697292308},
    
        {"item" : "InternalTemperature",
            "value": 22.2,
            "time" : 1518697292308}].reduce(function(carry, item) {
        carry[0][item['item']] = item['value'];
        carry[0]['time'] = item['time'];
        return carry;
    }, [{}])
    
  document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: What is a "`map` function"?

Comment: @UweKeim basic Array.prototype functions from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: How do I test it with document.write?

Comment: @Madula You need to stringify object before write it